# Spring MVC 3.1 - Request Header Character Encoding issue [UTF-8]

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm trying to get file name from request header, I'm getting character encoding problem despite I have defined **Spring encoding filter in my web.xml**.

```
String fileName = request.getHeader("X-File-Name"); // wrong encoding
```

web.xml

```
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Also I've added `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` config into Tomcat server.xml file.
And added same config JAVA_OPTS too.

```
-DuriEncoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the headers are always in UTF-8 (or ascii otherwise), you could do this:

```
public static String reEncode( String input ) {
    Charset w1252 = Charset.forName("Windows-1252"); //Superset of ISO-8859-1
    Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    return new String(input.getBytes(w1252), utf8 );
}

...

String fileName = reEncode("MekanizmasÄ±.pdf"); //request.getHeader("X-File-Name")
System.out.println(fileName); //Mekanizması.pdf
```

Comment: thank you so much Esailija for your help, now I'm able to get the right value.

Comment: Very brittle, since there so char encoding guarantee for HTTP headers.

Comment: @Michael-O yes, that's why it says either UTF-8 or ASCII. If it's in some other random encoding, he will see mojibake. I would recommend a normal query parameter as well, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

There is no encoding defined for HTTP headers. Expect them to support at most ISO-8859-1. Better rely on US-ASCII. The param is, as the name says, for URIs and their params. Nothing else.

Comment: I see, so how can I get the right value of file from HTTP-Header?

Comment: @talha06 what is the value you are getting now?

Comment: for example I'm getting "Onay MekanizmasÄ±.pdf" instead of "Onay Mekanizması.pdf" which is the right file name.

Comment: Forget about the header. ARe you performing a `PUT`?. If yes, use the URI. This is the only safe way. If you are `POST`ing with multipart. This works automatically.